# Ошибка при наследование фрейма: Error creating form: Ancestor for 'TMyFrame' not found

Tags: delphi, vcl

Имеется модуль BaseForms, в котором описан класс, наследуемый от TFrame:

```
TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
...
end;
```

Далее создаю фрейм отдельно: File -> New -> VCL Frame и наследуюсь от TMyFrame:

```
TCustomFrame = class(TMyFrame)
...
end;
```

Далее в dfm файле 'CustomFrame' меняю object на inherited:

```
inherited CustomFrame: TCustomFrame
end
```

При закрытии и открытие фрейма выходит ошибка: `Error creating form: Ancestor for 'TMyFrame' not found`.
Чтобы решить эту ошибку создаю dfm файл 'MyFrame.dfm' для TMyFrame:

```
object MyFrame: TMyFrame
end
```

Подключаю dfm файл к модулю:

```
{$R MyFrame.dfm}
```

Но выходит все та же ошибка. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не надо руками в dfm файл лезть. В pas файле в uses подключите юнит в котором объявлен TMyFrame и всё!

Comment: Скорее всего dproj не распознаёт, что модуль BaseForms является визуальным со всеми вытекающими. Нужно: 1. переименовать MyFrame.dfm в BaseForms.dfm  (не забыть {$R туда же) 2) исключить BaseForms из проекта и включить его обратно. А в остальном всё правильно, но всё же лучше создавать такое через New->Inheritable items.